# How to copy partition table in sfdisk and edit last partition to use all free space?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk, partition-copy

I've seen a number of variations on this, but nothing that puts all the parts together. I'm doing this on a Linux system

I know I can use `sfdisk /dev/sda <table.txt` to copy a partition table. Then I can use `sfdisk /dev/sda <table.txt` use that data to recreate the same table on a new disk.

I can also specify a partition that uses all the free space left on a disk with something like `echo 'start=2048, type=83' | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdb`.

What I want to do is use the first method, but edit `table.txt` in my batch file so the last partition in that file will now fill up all the remaining free space. This way if I'm copying a partition table to a larger or smaller sized disk, the last partition will use all available space. (We'll take as given that I'll be sure I'm not copying more data to the source than the new drive can hold if it's a smaller size than the original.)

For example, if I have a table like this:

```
label: dos
label-id: 0xe5e884c6
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=        8192, size=      524288, type=e, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=      532480, size=   245227520, type=83
```

What do I do for the size for /dev/sda2 to specify to use the rest of the free space for it? I tried specifying a 0, -1, and nothing for the size value for that partition and none of them worked.

My goal is to have a subroutine as part of a bash script that will read the partition table from one drive, make the change I've mentioned (with something like sed or awk) in the file, then use the edited file to create a partition table on a second drive that will will make the last partition as big as possible. While I was thinking this would be fairly easy to do the way I'm describing, I'm open to other ways to do this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while `sfdisk` is great for cloning a partition table without modification, I would recommend switching to using `parted` if you want to alter some partitions.

I don't know how to clone a partition table with `parted` so I'd keep sfdisk for that part:

`sfdisk -d /dev/sourcedisk | sfdisk /dev/newdisk`

The next lines in your batch script could make use of the command `parted resizepart` to use all the available space on the new disk.

`parted /dev/newdisk -s resizepart 2 100%`

Comment: The one issue I see with this is if I'm copying to a smaller drive. (Like I said, I would check that first to make sure I'm not copying too much data for a smaller drive.)

Comment: Okay, solved that problem. Go into the partition table and change the size of the 2nd partition to 1. Use sfdisk to read that table in and use it, then use parted as you describe. The only issue is that, at least for the version of Raspberry Pi OS that I'm using, it auto-mounts the devices after they're partitioned, so I need to go through and umount them. I'm going to write a function that will list all partitions mounted from that drive and umount them before repartition and before extending the last partition. (Just documenting it for others!)